# Is condition evaluation optimized ? Is this code bad?

Tags: c++, optimization, conditional-statements, logical-operators, evaluation

1.Imagine condition `if (obj.is_x() || obj.is_y() || obj.is_z())`
Will `obj.is_y()` and `obj.is_z()` be called and evaluated if `obj.is_x()` returned true ?

2.Is this a bad idea(in general)? Does this code look bad  ?

```
bool isbn13_prefix_valid (const string& prefix)
{
    unsigned num = stoi(prefix);
    if (num == 978 || num == 979) return 1;  //super common ones
        else if (   num >= 0 && num <= 5 || num == 7 || num >= 600 && num <= 649
                || num >= 80 && num <= 94 || num >= 950 && num <= 989
                || num >= 9900 && num <= 9989 || num >= 99900 && num <= 99999)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least use symbolic constants for these values. Then you should think of refactoring each condition into a single method with a self explanatory name.

Comment: `if (num == 978 || num == 979) return 1;  //super common ones
        else if`   Get rid of the else, it is superfluous.  The last condition is the same as `num == 999`.

Comment: Error prone, hard to understand, no intuitive meaning, too long.

Comment: @UweAllner: Good advice if you want to impress your boss by stating the number of lines of code you have written. Bad advice if you want a job done. Much better to add a comment with the spec that asks for this strange list of values.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: What do you mean by "not intuitive"? It's absolutely obvious. Which you would realise if you typed "isbn prefix" into google. For anyone in the problem domain it is obvious. And with the function name, it should be obvious to anyone who has ever read a book.

Comment: @gnasher729 You'd like to "see a comment where these strange numbers come from", too, so it must not be _that_ obvious. It's a too long combination of &&'s and ||'s, if you ask me - which is what the OP did: "Does this code look bad?". Yes, it does look bad to me.

Comment: To get the job done is one thing; to be able to read the own code a week later is the other. My boss does not care about the lines of code; he and me are just interested in readable and maintainable code. And a good compiler just optimizes the code by inlining small methods anyway.

Answer (score 7):

1. No, it will not, due to [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
2. Yes, that code looks bad. Not because it's incorrect, but because you're stuffing an extremely long conditional into a single `if` statement. Try refactoring your code to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine. I'd like to see a comment where these strange numbers come from, that's all.

Turning it into a dozen trivial functions as has been suggested is in no way helpful. It actually makes it a lot harder to read the code, because it gets spread out over many many lines of code. Yes, it is complex. But that's due to the problem being complex, and trying to spread the complexity out doesn't help one bit.

Your actual question: In a || b, a is evaluated first. If it is true, then b is not evaluated and the result is true. If a is false, then b is also evaluated and the result is true or false, depending on the result of b.

An optimising compiler may start evaluating b before it has finished evaluating a, if it can prove that the evaluation of b has no side effects, and if it believes that (mostly due to parallelism in the hardware) it is on average faster to evaluate as much in parallel as possible, even if some things are evaluated when it wasn't necessary. But this is not noticable in the results of your code, and will only make the code faster.